# Объясните о взаимодействие акселерометра и датчика магнитного поля в смартфоне

Tags: android

В общем, к чему вопрос: ковыряю Студию, чтобы сделать приложение, которое покажет угол поворота девайса, ниже приведу два кода. В первом случае используется гироскоп. Я поворачиваю смартфон - получаю угол, на который я его повернул. Но тут очень большая погрешность, если можно так сказать. Если поворачивать телефон очень медленно, то угол считаться вообще не будет.
Во втором случае используется акселерометр и магнитное поле. И считает очень точно - не важно быстро я поворачию смартфон или нет. 
Что касается первого случая, то там все предельно просто с точки зрения кода (хотя не понимаю, почему так криво считает), а во втором коде я не могу разобраться. Уже все по строчке прочитал по несколько раз, но все равно не могу понять это взаимодействие. Может кто-нибудь разжевать или направить, куда идти изучать инфу. Можно забугорную

Фрагмент кода с гироскопом

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
SensorEventListener {

private float rotateY = 0f;
private SensorManager sensorManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
super.onResume();

sensorManager.registerListener(this, 
sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE),
        SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
super.onPause();
sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

float degree = Math.round(event.values[1]);
rotateY += degree;
Log.d("TAG", "rotateY: " + rotateY);
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
}
}
```

Фрагмент кода с акселерометром и магнитным полем

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TextView tvText;
SensorManager sensorManager;
Sensor sensorAccel;
Sensor sensorMagnet;

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

Timer timer;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tvText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvText);
    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    sensorAccel = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    sensorMagnet = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    sensorManager.registerListener(listener, sensorAccel, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    sensorManager.registerListener(listener, sensorMagnet, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

    timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    getDeviceOrientation();
                    showInfo();
                }
            });
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(task, 0, 10);

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    sensorManager.unregisterListener(listener);
    timer.cancel();
}

String format(float values[]) {
    return String.format("%1$.1f\t\t%2$.1f\t\t%3$.1f", values[0], values[1], values[2]);
}

void showInfo() {
    sb.setLength(0);
    sb.append("Orientation : " + format(valuesResult));
    tvText.setText(sb);
}

float[] r = new float[9];

void getDeviceOrientation() {
    SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(r, null, valuesAccel, valuesMagnet);
    SensorManager.getOrientation(r, valuesResult);

    valuesResult[0] = (float) Math.toDegrees(valuesResult[0]);
    valuesResult[1] = (float) Math.toDegrees(valuesResult[1]);
    valuesResult[2] = (float) Math.toDegrees(valuesResult[2]);
    return;
}


float[] valuesAccel = new float[3];
float[] valuesMagnet = new float[3];
float[] valuesResult = new float[3];



SensorEventListener listener = new SensorEventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {



        switch (event.sensor.getType()) {
            case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
                for (int i=0; i < 3; i++){
                    valuesAccel[i] = event.values[i];
                }
                break;
            case Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD:
                for (int i=0; i < 3; i++){
                    valuesMagnet[i] = event.values[i];
                }
                break;
        }
    }
};
```

}

Второй код брал с этой [статьи](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/287-urok-137-sensory-uskorenie-orientatsija.html)

Answer (score -1):

Нашел химию этих отношений [здесь](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#SENSOR_STATUS_ACCURACY_HIGH). Абзац `getRotationMatrix`.
А код с гироскопом так криво работает, потому что это же скорость вращения в рад/c, это я не догнал сразу